# Getting number of wall posts on an event page

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I was wondering how I could get the number of wall posts for a facebook `event` page so I can display it next to a link on my page. The only thing I could find is:

```
SELECT comment_count FROM link_stat WHERE url="https://www.facebook.com/events/579589685427085"
```

Which is only return 0 even though there are posts on that wall

Answer (score 0):

Get all the posts by

```
var client= new facebookclient("accessToken");

JsonObject allData = (JsonObject)client.Get("me/feed");
```

here `allData` variable will contain all the post of your wall.
now you can use it `foreach` loop to compare with your specific url feed and use it which you need from it.